# Using SubProcess in Python for Awk

Tags: python, git, unix, awk, subprocess

I am trying to run this command `git status -vv | awk 'NR>5 {print $0}'` from within a Python file. But I cannot get the awk command working.

Here is a sample result of my git st:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of master by 2 commits.
#
#
#       modified:   file1
#       modified:   file2
#       modified:   file3
```

When I run the command from the terminal, I get what I want:

```
#       modified:   file1
#       modified:   file2
#       modified:   file3
```

I am having trouble implementing it from within a Python script:

```
import sys
import subprocess as sb

ps = sb.Popen(("git","status","-vv"),stdout=sb.PIPE)
output = sb.check_output(('awk','"NR>5 {print $0}"'),stdin=ps.stdout)
print output
```

However, this returns just the git st results without the awk performed on the lines. How can I do this from within python to get the same output as I do when running in the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work (just remove the double quotes for awk's argument)

```
import sys
import subprocess as sb

ps = sb.Popen(("git","status","-vv"),stdout=sb.PIPE)
output = sb.check_output(('awk','NR>5 {print $0}'),stdin=ps.stdout)
print output
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. And kudos for actually looking at my provided code and catching a fix instead of just recommending to use `shell=True` !

Comment: I think for awk subprocess.check_ouput(...) is the correct way to run this command for `shell= False`. This worked for me too

Answer (score 0):

This might be much simpler:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                                                                                                                                 

import sys
import subprocess as sb

cmd = "git status -vv | awk '(NR>5){ print $0 }'"

output = sb.check_output(cmd, stderr=sb.STDOUT, shell=True)
sys.stdout.write('{}'.format(output))
```